# How to recover WSL 1 from old system disk and use on new system

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows broke after updating. I couldn't fix it, so I can't access it from the system.

On the old system, I was using WSL 1 from Ubuntu. I didn't backup or export.

I would like to try to reclaim this whole environment before I start recreating it.

For WSL 2, the location `C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\` would have a disk image. WSL 1 has a Linux-like directory structure.

I created WSL on the new system and installed the same version of Ubuntu as on the old system.

Maybe copying these directories from the old computer to the new one would help, but I don't know how to do it from Windows so as not to mess with the linux file permissions

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: You can probably `rsync` your original folder tree into the WSL2 instance.  Also.. I myself *prefer* WSL1 and use it everywhere I don't need unsupported kernel stuff (like Docker).  Nothing stopped you from using WSL1 in your new setup.

Comment: Just a heads-up that I asked that your question be migrated from Stack Overflow (since it isn't about programming) here.  Note that you don't need to create a new account here - You can just log in with the same username/password you used on Stack Overflow, since they are both part of the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

I went through a similar experience myself a few years ago when I needed to do a Windows "Reset".  I had done a `wsl --export`, but I fell into that age-old trap of not testing the backup/restore, and the import would never complete when it came time to restore.

In your case though, I've gone back-and-forth on this.  My conclusion is that you're *probably* in the same boat that I was.  You'll need to copy over individual files, but restoring the entire filesystem isn't a good idea.

> Maybe copying these directories from the old computer to the new one would help, but I don't know how to do it from Windows so as not to mess with the linux file permissions

Absolutely correct - It's the permissions and ownership that potentially cause the issue.

The Linux metadata is stored in NTFS Extended Attributes (according to [this Microsoft devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)).  *If* you can guarantee that you are copying over the EAs, then you could:

- Create a new Ubuntu 20.04 WSL1 distribution on the new PC
- Delete the new `rootfs`
- Copy over the old `rootfs`

But I have no good way to tell you how to ensure that the EAs are copied properly, other than if the Linux permissions and owners show up correctly, and even if you could, you can't check every file in the filesystem.  It's extremely odd to me that there's no built-in Windows functionality (other than in the kernel/API) to examine and modify EAs.  There seem to be third party libraries out there for PowerShell, but I haven't gone so far as to try them out to examine WSL1 EAs.

If I went the "Copy" route, I'd probably always be suspect of the WSL1 installation myself, so I'd probably still go the route I originally did and:

- Install a fresh WSL1 distribution on the new PC.
- Reinstall/reconfigure apps and services -- Copy over the old `/var/log/apt/history.log` to a temporary location and run `grep "^Commandline" history.log` to get a list of packages you had installed.
- Copy over any configuration from `/etc/` that you can remember.  You can just copy the *text* of the config files from old to new rather than potentially messing up permissions by copying the files themselves.
- Copy over just files from my old home directory that I knew I could then modify easily with a `chmod`/`chown`.